# Fetch files from from firebase storage using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have this screen called **HomePage** where there are different posts.
all the data stored in the cloud store and user profile is store in firebase storage.
and I m storing user image in such way that user's Phone Number is fileName of the user's image.
and I want to fetch users Image corresponding to their Phone Number which is fileName and yes Phone Number is stored in firebase cloud.
 [image]

Comment: i think if when youre saving user image you can get the link and save it .

Answer (score 0):

[This article is one of best tutorial for firebase storage and flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/loading-image-from-firebase-storage-in-flutter-app-android-ios-web-1951607ec9ef)

Accordingly this will return a Image widget. Pass `context` and  `Phone Number`

```
Future<Widget> _getImage(BuildContext context, String image) async {
    Image m;
    await FireStorageService.loadImage(context, image).then((downloadUrl) {
        m = Image.network(
            downloadUrl.toString(),
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        );
    });
    return m;
}
```

First of all you have to setup `firebase storage service` and `firebase storage rules`as described in above tutorial.